# Decoding custom encrypted file

Tags: java, encryption, bit-manipulation

I am currently working with save files of an old game.
My problem is that the file is encrypted with a custom algorithm.
I only have a vague description of it:

"The file is encrypted by adding 39393939 and then rotating each DWord right 5 bits."

I tried to reverse the progress with this java code on each 4 byte block ()

```
private static byte[] decryptDWord(byte[] in) {
    //in is 4 bytes

    IntBuffer buf=ByteBuffer.wrap(in).asIntBuffer();
    int dword=buf.get();
    dword=Integer.rotateLeft(dword, 5);
    dword -=0x39393939;
    byte[] out = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(dword).array();

    return out;
}
```

But applied on `0x70, 0x4E, 0x33, 0x43` it should give me `0x73, 0x63, 0x30, 0x2E` and on `0x74, 0x60, 0x33, 0x03` should give `0x73, 0x63, 0x34, 0x20`

Comment: Wait, it says "DWord". One Word is 32 bits (4 bytes), in my sense. In other words, a doubleword should correlate to a `long` (64 bits / 8 byte), shouldn't it?

Comment: according to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29#Size_families a WORD is 16 bit and a DWORD ist 32 bit=4bytes

Comment: Ok then, but I still don't understand your example. If I use `calc.exe` (set to `DWORD` programmer mode), if I enter `704E3343`, then rotate the bits 5 to the left, I get  `9C6686E`, then I subtract `39393939` and I get `D08D2F35`, which is the **exact** output of the function you gave before (calling it with `byte[] dec = decryptDWord(new byte[] {0x70, 0x4E, 0x33, 0x43  });` then displaying one byte at a time). So, that function actually works. (See http://goo.gl/lhLewr for a an tutorialspoint.com online java compiler example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Size_families) size is machine-dependent, most likely in this context `DWORD` is 4 bytes long, so in java it corresponds to `int`.
Also, you must take to account that original architecture might be [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit) or [MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) in both terms, bits and bytes, so pack separate bytes yourself into 'int' possibly changing the order of bits: totally 4 different combinations. Then you first need to rotate left 5 bits and then subtract 39393939. After 'decryption' you need to restore the original byte/bit order probably.